# What is the proper idiom for using the built in Guice Injection for annotating static java.util.Logger instances?

Tags: java, logging, guice, idioms, java.util.logging

I want to start using Guice 3.x to magically inject my `java.util.logging.Logger` instances.

Here is a snippet of code I am trying to get to work:

```
@Singleton
public class Main
{
    @Inject
    private static final Logger logger;

...
}
```

This doesn't seem to work.

I get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException` no matter what scope I use on the declaration.

I added the line `super.requestStaticInjection(Main.class);` to my `module` in the `configure()` method and it started working, but only if I remove the `final` keyword and make it `static Logger logger`.

I would prefer to keep the Logger `final` if at all possible.

**What is the proper idiomatic Guice way of doing this?**

Comment: I don't do Guice, but it makes perfect sense to me that injecting a `static final` "property" (it's actually a constant) is simply not possible. All depencency injection frameworks I know also disallows this. Does it work if you get rid of those constraints?

Comment: changed it to `@Inject public Logger logger` and all scopes in between, and still get errors. I like to mark anything that is immutable as `final` and having an instance of a `Logger` on every object isn't good either way.

Comment: Well, it might be a Guide configuration issue. What errors do you get by the way? Ones who are familiar with Guice may be able to translate them for you in layman's terms so that you understand the cause and therefore see the solution.

Comment: @BalusC, you're completely right. There's no way for Guice to set up a final static property. That's the way Java is designed and what *final* modifier is exactly for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inject into static properties in guice with e.g.

```
class Dummy {
   @Inject static Foo;
}
```

and

```
requestStaticInjection(Dummy.class);
```

in the injector configureModule.

Comment: is there some magic incantation to allow me to make it final as well?

Comment: I'm afraid not... Since final properties are  set to `null` right when your class loads. All object fields are initialized with default values, unless otherwise (explicitly) stated, when the object is instantiated. All unset (not set in any constructor or static initialization block) *static* fields receive default values during class load. So, when you want it to be set up it's already too late, since it already hold `null`.

Comment: thanks for the confirmation of what I discovered while waiting on an answer!

Answer (score 0):

Guice *does* allow final field injections, however it's not recommended

> The binding's value is set into the field. Injecting final fields is not recommended because the injected value may not be visible to other threads.

[source](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/InjectionPoints#How_Guice_Injects), also be avare of all the caveats of [set()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#set%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29).

This means **you can have a final field, but not a static final field injected**.

> If the underlying field is final, the method throws an IllegalAccessException unless setAccessible(true) has succeeded for this field and this field is non-static.

On the other hand [JSR 330](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=330) does not allow injection of final fields.